# The expected number of ball tosses to get a ball in a specific bin.

Tags: probability, expectation, balls-in-bins

Given n bins, and toss balls, each toss the ball is equally like to end up in any bin. If a bin get a ball, move this bin away so that following tosses will not fall in this bin again, what's the expected number of ball tosses to get a ball in a specific bin.

Comment: @Arthur I figured out that the probability of a specific bin get a hit is always 1/n, but I don’t know how to calculate the expectation. I don’t know if it’s correct that I am trying to add up 1 to k times tosses’ expectations and solve the k to that the sum is equal to 1.

Comment: A good start may be to work the problem completely for small $n$.  $n=1, 2,3$ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for alternate approach: Say you have $n$ balls as well, and they are numbered. And you throw all of them in order, regardless of whether you already hit the specified bin. Then each bin has a numbered ball in it, and the number of throws it took to hit the specific bin is exactly equal to the number on the ball in it. What is the expected number on that ball?

Comment: It’s (1+n)/2 I guess.

Comment: @ryuu That is my guess too. There is no reason to believe any ball is more likely than any other ball to get into the specified bin.

Comment: I just don’t know why my equation is not working. The expectation of k tosses is k/n, so the sum(total expectation) is (k^2 + k)/n, if this sum is equal to 1, then the expectation of that bin get a hit is 1, and solve the k I get the expected tosses.

Comment: "The expectation of k tosses is k/n, so the sum(total expectation) is (k^2 + k)/n" $k$ should've disappeared from that last expression. What you do there is summing over all possible $k$ from $1$ to $n$:
$$
\frac 1n + \frac2n + \cdots + \frac{n-1}n + \frac nn
$$There are no letters $k$ in that expression, nor should there be.

Comment: OK, guess I have to review the textbook and figure out what exactly does expectation mean. Anyway, thanks a lot. This alternative approach is very intuitive and heuristic.